# Time a fundamental force?

Tags: time

If time is emergent especially immediately after big bang then is it a fundamental force that appeared at that moment

Comment: This is just a non sequitur

Comment: what is your definition of force to make you think time satisfy it?

Comment: This site only deals with **mainstream physics**.  This question is about a completely speculative idea that does not really fall under this rubric.  If you have a more precise notion of what you are asking about, it is possible that you might be able to convert this into an on-topic question, but as it stands, this is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

No, because the very definitions of the terms "fundamental force" and "emergent property" are incompatible. If it's emergent (which it very well may be), then it is definitely not fundamental.